# Chaining one router to another plus a switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall

So I have a hardware firewall running OPNsense, a dumb switch, and a router. Could I run the output of the firewall through the switch, have the firewall do DHCP for those running off that, then connect the router to the switch as well to assign DHCP to wifi clients? Or do I need to run the switch off the router instead of directly off the firewalls output.

[Extra Info]
Hardware firewall is a precision 390 with an extra NIC in it
Switch is a TP Link TL-SF1048 passive switch.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys I got it, thanks for the help. Here's my solution for anyone who might run into this problem in the future.

Run the first as a router with DHCP

Install DDWRT (Not necessary)

Hook the Lan ports of the two routers together?

Change the second router to have a static ip identical to the primary but plus one (ie 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2)

That should allow the second router to function as an AP for the first.